# How to extract a list of handlebars from a template?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Given a string with valid handlebars, like `"Handlebars <b>{{doesWhat}}</b>"`, I know I can compile it using `Handlebars.compile` so I can inject a variable to `doesWhat` with the following code:

```js
const template = Handlebars.compile("Handlebars <b>{{doesWhat}}</b>");
const rendered = template({ doesWhat: "rocks!" });
// returns "Handlebars <b>rocks!</b>"
```

I am wondering if there is a way to extract the list of all handlebars detected upon compilation by the library (excluding comments, helpers or other features of the "language")? Something that would return:

```js
['doesWhat']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for a solution and could not find a proper one.

The best way is to convert the template to AST and extract data from it

Reference: https://github.com/handlebars-lang/handlebars.js/blob/master/docs/compiler-api.md

```js
const result = []

class ExpressionScanner extends Handlebars.Visitor {
  MustacheStatement({
    path,
    params
  }) {
    if (params && params.length > 0) {
      result.push(params[0].original)
    } else {
      result.push(path.original)
    }
  }
}

const template = '{{name}} <b>{{loud does}}</b> my <b>{{thing.value}}</b>!'

const ast = Handlebars.parseWithoutProcessing(template)

const scanner = new ExpressionScanner()
scanner.accept(ast)

document.querySelector('#expressions').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)

document.querySelector('#ast').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(ast, null, 2)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<pre id="expressions"></pre>
<pre id="ast"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way could be to use regex on the string.

```js
let result = "Handlebars <b>{{doesWhat}}</b> <b>{{example}}</b>".match(/{{[{]?(.*?)[}]?}}/g)

console.log(result)
```

Although, there can certainly be a better solution than this.

Comment: This will work for basic templates like these ones, but as soon as we use comments, hooks or helpers it will not behave correctly, still +1 though

Answer (score 1):

You should match anything within `"{{"` and `"}}"`. This does not account for things such as loops and repeaters.

I added look behind and look ahead checks. Keep in mind that older versions of JavaScript don't support negative look behinds.

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('loud', str => str.toUpperCase())

const EXPRESSION_PATTERN = /(?<=\{\{)[\{]?(.*?)[\}]?(?=\}\})/g
const extractExpressions = template => format.match(EXPRESSION_PATTERN)

let format  = '{{name}} <b>{{loud does}}</b> my <b>{{thing.value}}</b>!'
let options = { name: 'Handlebars', does: 'rocks', thing: { value: 'socks' }}
let template = Handlebars.compile(format)

console.log(extractExpressions(template))
document.querySelector('#rendered').innerHTML = template(options)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.6/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<div id="rendered"></div>
```

Comment: It's actually stronger than the other solution but doesn't give me the list of handlebars: what I expect with `loud does` is to receive `does`, and also exclude comments - it will actually suit my need with little tweaking since I don't use a lot of helpers